# Can French citizens apply for a South Korean tourist visa with the ongoing COVID-19 travel restrictions?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, covid-19, south-korea, french-citizens

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_South_Korea&oldid=966979960#Visa-free_entry:

> On 13 April 2020, the South Korean government temporarily suspended its visa waiver agreement with 56+34 countries due to them suspending their visa waiver agreement with South Korean nationals. The suspension of visa free access to those nationals of the 56+34 countries [which include France] will last until the South Korean government can agree that the spread of Covid-19 is under control.

Can French citizens apply for a South Korean tourist visa with the ongoing COVID-19 travel restrictions that resulted in the South Korean government temporarily suspending its visa waiver agreement (which included France)?

Comment: You do understand that if you were able to get a tourist visa, you would be required to spend 14 days in managed quarantine on arrival in South Korea, right?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk unless the policy has changed your statement is incorrect, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157051/1810 what's your source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Embassy of the Republic of Korea to the Republic of Singapore's  webpage](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/sg-en/brd/m_2435/view.do?seq=761248&fbclid=IwAR1D8zXiWbMzJAoAODpqHY5GHxrG3ecnjWVvt1oxcmP4-sz0ThzbRQHfyBU) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/8w2BF)):

> As of 09 April 2020 foreigners who need to enter Korea due to necessary reasons (**excluding tourism**) may apply for visa at our office in person. Interview may be conducted.

Therefore you can't apply for a Tourism Visa with the ongoing travel restrictions.

The suspension of Short-Term Visa and Visa Free Entry is still in effect. Visa requirements may change anytime. Consult the [Republic of Korea Embassy in France](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/fr-fr/index.do) for the most up-to-date information regarding visa's and travel restrictions.