# How to know which East Asian country accepts tourists who resided in Thailand since the Covid-19 pandemic started?

Tags: international-travel, thailand, covid-19, southeast-asia, east-asia

I hold Israeli citizenship and passport and I am currently residing in Bangkok for nearly two years already - I haven't visited Israel since I came here. I don't hold Israeli residency status (i.e I am "a citizen which isn't a resident").

### My problem

My current Thailand visa is amnesty visa which should end on 26/09/20;
If I won't be able to obtain a new (non-amnesty) visa, I do plan to stay somewhere in east Asia or in a nearby part of Oceania, but I don't know how to find out where efficiently.

### My question

Because I plan to stay as near as to Thailand as I can (for 3-6 months), I ask:
How to know which east asian country accept tourists who resided in Thailand since the Covid-19 pandemic started?

A better question might be:
Is there some global resource to know where one who resided in country X enough time (say, Thailand) is allowed to fly to in Covid-19 crisis time?

Comment: It's not exactly East Asia, and until very recently would have been off limits to Israelis, but the UAE (!) might be an option: https://gulfnews.com/uae/government/dubai-travel-guidelines-for-tourists-visitors-from-july-7-1.1592794540210

Comment: @lambshaanxy I actually thought about it surprisingly when it was published; this Netanyahu knows very well what card to draw to stay relevant in the coming Israeli elections. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at https://travelbans.org/crossing-rules/?from=Thailand to see which countries are accessible from Thailand, or https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm to check each country one by one. There are a few other websites mentioned on [Is there any website or service for showing countries / regions open for travel during Covid-19 restrictions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157511/1810)

Anyway I'm in the same situation (in Bangkok and trying to avoid going into the western covid-full countries) and from I can see all countries in East Asia are currently closed to tourists who doesn't have some Asian passports. Indonesia at some point had hinted they'd reopened in September but the plan seems to have been reversed. This is reckless from governments to force people to exit covid-free countries, but that's no surprise since the covid-19 pandemic is mostly a stupidity pandemic.

---

Screenshot of https://travelbans.org/crossing-rules/?from=Thailand  ([mirror 1](https://archive.vn/4nKIm), [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200818174440/https://travelbans.org/crossing-rules/?from=Thailand)):

[image]

FYI South Korea isn't currently open to tourists: [Can French citizens apply for a South Korean tourist visa with the ongoing COVID-19 travel restrictions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158823/1810)